# Show array range including special characters in visual studio watch window.

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

If I have the following code:

```
char u_buf[50] = "AB\0C\0D\r\c12345 ...
char *buf = u_buf;
```

Is there a way that i can view the data in this buffer over a certain range in visual studio's watch window? If i watch `buf` i will just get `AB`.

Can I maybe cast it to something else that visual studio watches differently? Cast to `uint8_t*` displays the same, visual studio still seems to interpret it as a string.

What i would like to be able to view is the first 40 elements (it is binary data).

Comment: Did you try `buf,40` ? (I've not got a VS to hand to try this on, should work though)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can type "buf, 50" into your "Watch Window" while debugging with `buf` in scope:**

[image]

To open a "Watch Window" go to "Debug" > "Windows" > "Watch" > "Watch #" or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>#</kbd> where "#" is the index of the "Watch Window" you wish to open.

**Alternatively you can type `buf`'s address into the "Memory Window" (here "0x0025FC74") and you'll be able to keep an eye on the contents whether or not `buf` is in scope:**

[image]

To open a "Memory Window" go to "Debug" > "Windows" > "Memory" > "Memory #" or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>#</kbd> where "#" is the index of the "Memory Window" you wish to open.

Comment: As a follow up, how did you know that, the best i can find from the `watch` documentation is this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2t7ahxk.aspx and thats not helpful at all ...

Comment: @Ben How did I know about the "Memory Window"? I had a brilliant boss, last company I worked at: https://www.linkedin.com/in/benjamin-baker-03624570 I aspire to someday know as much as he did.